# LAMPP Error #1932 after update: Tables don't exist

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp

I recently updated my Ubuntu server, and now all the tables in my database are telling me they don't exist.

I had some issues with phpMyAdmin after restarting the machine, so I reinstalled it and eventually got it working again. I can see the database and it lists all of the tables, but as soon as I click on any it says "Table xxx.xxxx doesn't exist in engine". I can see the files are still there in nautilus.

I have done a lot of research and I see some general information about rebuilding the tables, but I don't usually do anything in a LAMPP environment and I can't lose any of this data, so I've been wary about running some of the commands (especially the ones that include DROP).
I am running XAMPP for Linux 5.6.23 and phpMyAdmin 4.5.2 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you take a backup of your database(s) before changing the the database server?

Comment: Might be an issue with a storage engine not installed inside the mysql server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I did not (which I realize was very stupid).

Comment: @arkascha Can you elaborate? How would I go about checking?

Comment: Not sure, I'd say you need to know or find out what storage engine those tables were build on. A good start would be to take the storage folder and drop it into a mysql setup using an older version, a virtual machine or a docker container might be a good alternative for that... That would also enable you to make a clean backup dump if you get the older version to accept that data folder.

Comment: @arkascha I believe they are InnoDB

Comment: So, is InnoDb installed? And certainly _knowing_ would be safer than _believing_... computer science has not so much in common with religion, fortunately.

Comment: @arkascha I ran a recovery tool one one of the .frm files and it told me the type was InnoDB.  I'm not sure why InnoDB wouldn't be installed since I did not remove it.  I originally had XAMPP and PHPmyadmin installed and just removed/reinstalled them and nothing else.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engines.html

Comment: @arkascha Yep, it is there and set as the default

Comment: Ok, that was just an idea... So I suggest you give my hint from above a try to install an older version of mysql in some container and try to load the storage folder into that.

Comment: Any hints in the MySQL logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up solving this eventually.  I used https://recovery.twindb.com/ to recover the frm files and rebuilt the database tables one at a time using the MySQL CLI.  I removed and reinstalled XAMPP and phpMyAdmin and finally got it all working after dumping and then importing.